# How to use sequelize-typescript for querying relative objects through custom Apollo GraphQL resolver?

Tags: graphql, sequelize.js, apollo-server, sequelize-typescript, graphql-codegen

How to use [sequelize-typescript](https://npmjs.com/package/sequelize-typescript) for querying relative objects through custom Apollo GraphQL type? I have the following query without typescript:

**User** and **Event** GraphQL types:

```graphql
type User {
    id: Int
    login: String
    email: String
    role: Roles
    url_identity: String
}

type Event {
  id: Int
  event_name: String
  user: User
}
```

User model

```js
import {HasOne, Model, Table} from "sequelize-typescript";
import Event from "./event.model";

@Table({
    timestamps: false,
    modelName: 'User',
})
export default class User extends Model {

    @HasOne(() => Event)
    event: Event
}
```

Resolver:

```js
static resolver() {
    return {
        Event: {
            user: event => event.$get('user')
    }
}
```

Typescript can't see `event.$get('user')`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to add **mappers** to your **graphql-codegen** config.
You can also pass interface for context (third parameter):

```yml
schema: ./src/graphql/types/**/*.graphql
generates:
  ./src/graphql/resolvers-types.ts:
    config:
      useIndexSignature: true
      contextType: ./schema#IApolloServerContext
      mappers:
        Event: ../database/models/event.model#EventModel
        User: ../database/models/user.model#UserModel
    plugins:
      - typescript
      - typescript-resolvers
```

More info here: https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/typescript-resolvers#use-your-model-types-mappers